# How to achieve reveal circular animation with menu rotation in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve this Circular Reveal animation with menu opening in a circular motion.

I am have it using the library below. What i have achieved till now :-

```
private Animator createShowItemAnimator(View item) {
    float dx = centerItem.getX() - item.getX();
    float dy = centerItem.getY() - item.getY();

    item.setScaleX(0f);
    item.setScaleY(0f);
    item.setTranslationX(dx);
    item.setTranslationY(dy);

    Animator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
            item,
            AnimatorUtils.scaleX(0f, 1f),
            AnimatorUtils.scaleY(0f, 1f),
            AnimatorUtils.translationX(dx, 0f),
            AnimatorUtils.translationY(dy, 0f)
    );

    anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(50);
    return anim;
}
```

Above code snippet is used to render the images ( **first screenshot**) in a sequential manner
https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout
[image]

I am stuck on the part where the 5 circular imageviews are to be opened in a circular motion in the second screenshot. Can someone help me regarding this ?

[image]

Comment: It might [help](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) you. scroll till **More circular reveal animations**

Comment: This i have tried but with no success

Comment: Your minSdkVersion ?

Comment: [Check](https://github.com/tiancaiCC/SpringFloatingActionMenu) this